# show side bar for iPad like facebook in landscapemode in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios7, sidebar

I am having an iPad app in which I want to implement a Side Bar functionality like we have in facebook app.

I am using this [Demo](https://github.com/inonb/SlideMenuController2) for this.

With this I have successfully implemented the Side Bar functionality and its working well but with that my first view doesn't show me well.

Below is the screenshot.

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot, there is a black background and my whole view is not showing in full screen when the app launches.

It should be like below.

[image]

Also on clicking the button the Side View is showing like below.

[image]

It should be small as I have taken the view size with width = 300 and height = 768.

But it is showing bigger than that.

Here is my code which I change in my appdelegate.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    [self createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];

    SlidingViewController *slidingView = [[SlidingViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SlidingViewController" bundle:nil];

    self.slideMenuController = [[SlideMenuController alloc] initWithCenterViewController:navController];
    self.slideMenuController.leftViewController = slidingView;

    self.window.rootViewController = navController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
   return YES;
}

- (IBAction)sideBarPressed:(id)sender
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if (appDelegate.slideMenuController.position == TKSlidePositionCenter) {
        [appDelegate.slideMenuController presentLeftViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    } else {
        [appDelegate.slideMenuController presentCenterViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

I want this for my iPad for **Landscape** mode only.

Please tell me What is wrong here?

I am stuck here for quite a while.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: wy u need to use this for iPad, there is one cool UISplitViewController for iPad check that out ... i think it suits for your case, in landscape mode this will show the menuController at the left side

Comment: I have implemented this code. If you can some changes in it to solve.

Comment: it is easy to integrate UISplitViewController, the above slider that u are using, which is specially designed to iPhone not for iPad

Comment: Ok so can you give me the demo code for that?

Comment: I posted the sample demo code check it out ..

Comment: @Shan:Hi shan. Please check this out http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49117/ios-help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I successfully implemented this side bar menu functionality with this [Demo code](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) and its working perfectly well in my case.

Hope it works to someone else also.

Thanks for your help and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

So better u need to use UISplitViewController

```
 //in app delegate do like this
 //in appDelegate.h file 
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

 @interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

 @property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) UISplitViewController *splitViewCOntroller; 
 @end


 //in appDelegate.m file
 #import "AppDelegate.h"
 #import "SplitMasterViewController.h"  //create a UITableviewController 
 #import "SplitViewDetailController.h"  //create a UIViewController

  @implementation AppDelegate
  @synthesize splitViewCOntroller = _splitViewCOntroller;

  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
   {
      // Override point for customization after application launch.
      SplitMasterViewController *masterController  = [[SplitMasterViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SplitMasterViewController" bundle:nil]; //this is the master menu controller

     UINavigationController *masterNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:masterController];

     SplitViewDetailController *detailViewController = [[SplitViewDetailController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SplitViewDetailController" bundle:nil]; //this is the master detail controller


     UINavigationController *detailNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];
masterController.detailViewController = detailViewController;

    _splitViewCOntroller = [[UISplitViewController alloc]init]; //initilise split controller
    _splitViewCOntroller.delegate = detailViewController;      //set the delegate to detail controller
    _splitViewCOntroller.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:masterNavController,detailNavController, nil]; //set the splitview controller
     self.window.rootViewController = _splitViewCOntroller; //finally your splitviewcontroller as the root view controller
     [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

     return YES;
 }


 //in SplitMasterViewController.h this must be a table that contains your side bar menu items 
 #import "ViewController.h" //comment this if it shows any error
 #import "SplitViewDetailController.h"

 @interface SplitMasterViewController :        UITableViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
 @property (nonatomic, retain) SplitViewDetailController *detailViewController; //to get the detailview from masterMenu controller 
 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *Names;

 @end 

 // in SplitMasterViewController.m file
 #import "SplitMasterViewController.h"
 #import "SplitViewDetailController.h"


 @interface SplitMasterViewController ()

 @end

 @implementation SplitMasterViewController

 @synthesize Names;
 @synthesize detailViewController;


 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
 {
     self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
     if (self) {
     // Custom initialization
      }
     return self;
  }

  - (void)viewDidLoad
  { 
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //  Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    Names = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"apple", @"banana",
             @"mango", @"grapes", nil];

    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:
    [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]
                            animated:NO
                      scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
   }

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
       return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
      return [Names count];
    }

   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                         dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     if (cell == nil) {
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
            initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
            reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

    // [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = [Names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
   }

   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
     SplitViewDetailController *detailController =  self.detailViewController;
     detailController.myLabel.text = [Names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //set the name from the array
 }

  - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
  {
     [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
     // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

  @end


  //in SplitViewDetailController.h
  #import "ViewController.h"

  @interface SplitViewDetailController : UIViewController<UISplitViewControllerDelegate>
  @property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;
  @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
  @property (nonatomic, retain) UIBarButtonItem *leftBarButtonItem; //to show a button on left side

  @end

 //in SplitViewDetailController.m 

 #import "SplitViewDetailController.h"

 @interface SplitViewDetailController ()
 {
   UIPopoverController *masterPopoverController;
 }

 @end

  @implementation SplitViewDetailController

  - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
  {
     self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
     if (self) {
      // Custom initialization
     }
     return self;
  }

  - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
    [super viewDidLoad];
     // _leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Menu" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:nil];
  }

  - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
  {
     [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
     // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }


  //these are the call back to detail view controller to hide or show the button
  - (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitController willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController  withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem  forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
 {
   _leftBarButtonItem = barButtonItem;
   _leftBarButtonItem.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
   _leftBarButtonItem.title = @"Menu";
   [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:_leftBarButtonItem animated:YES];
  }

  // Called when the view is shown again in the split view, invalidating the button
  - (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitController       willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
   {
      [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil animated:YES];
   }

  @end
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. But as I was in hurry so tried this demo https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController and it worked fine for me. But I will definitely try this Splitviewcontroller. Thanks once again. +1 for you.

Answer (score 0):

i am using this and it's good

https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController